# using ++ with jquery $.each()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the id value of the last image being shown which is the value in a checkbox. The id value looks like: "image_1, image_2 etc.

I just need the actual number so I have used the slice function to do so. If I upload 3 images for example, I then need to get the last id and increment by 1 for each new image added. So, if the last image is image_5 and I upload 3 new images, the new images should be image_6, image_7 and image_8. but the problem I am having is that all 3 images end up being image_6.

Original code:

```
//get the id value i.e.: image_1
$.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
var lastBox = $( 'input[name="pics[]"]' ).last().data("id");

// remove the image_ prefix to get the actual number value
var lastId = parseInt(lastBox.slice(6));

// increment each id by 1 in the $.each() loop
var total = lastId++;
console.log(total);
```

EDIT: Full code with answer incorporated:

```
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        var lastBox = $( 'input[name="pics[]"]' ).last().data("id");
        var lastId = parseInt(lastBox.slice(6));
        var total = lastId;
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            total++;
            console.log(total);
            $( "#gallery-body" ).prepend(`

                <div class="col-md-3 img-box">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="image_${total}" name="pics[]" value="${file.name}" data-id="image_${total}" />
                    <label for="image_${total}" style="background-image: url(uploads/${file.name})">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </label>
                </div>
                    `);
```

HTML OUTPUT:

```
<div class="col-md-3 img-box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="image_17" name="pics[]" value="IMG_5271.jpg" data-id="image_17">
    <label for="image_17" style="background-image: url(uploads/IMG_5271.jpg)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 img-box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="image_17" name="pics[]" value="dzone.jpg" data-id="image_17">
    <label for="image_17" style="background-image: url(uploads/dzone.jpg)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you appending new inputs in each iteration of the loop? If not, `lastBox` will be 5 in each iteration and `total` will be 6.

Comment: I am prepending new images which should have id's following on from whatever the last one was before new images were uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the last ID *before* the loop, then increment inside the loop.

And since you're adding new items at the front of the list, you should use `.first()` to get the highest numbered ID.

```js
var data = {
  result: {
    files: [{
      name: "IMG_5271.jpg"
    }, {
      name: "dzone.jpg"
    }]
  }
};

var lastBox = $('input[name="pics[]"]').first().data("id");
var lastId = parseInt(lastBox.slice(6));
var total = lastId;
$.each(data.result.files, function(index, file) {
  total++;
  console.log(total);
  $("#gallery-body").prepend(`

                <div class="col-md-3 img-box">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="image_${total}" name="pics[]" value="${file.name}" data-id="image_${total}" />
                    <label for="image_${total}" style="background-image: url(uploads/${file.name})">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </label>
                </div>
                    `);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery-body">
  <input type="checkbox" name="pics[]" data-id="image_4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="pics[]" data-id="image_3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="pics[]" data-id="image_2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="pics[]" data-id="image_1">
</div>
```

When I run this, the result is:

```html
<div id="gallery-body">

  <div class="col-md-3 img-box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="image_6" name="pics[]" value="dzone.jpg" data-id="image_6">
    <label for="image_6" style="background-image: url(uploads/dzone.jpg)">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-3 img-box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="image_5" name="pics[]" value="IMG_5271.jpg" data-id="image_5">
    <label for="image_5" style="background-image: url(uploads/IMG_5271.jpg)">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </label>
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" name="pics[]" data-id="image_4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="pics[]" data-id="image_3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="pics[]" data-id="image_2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="pics[]" data-id="image_1">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you suggested and still have the same issue. The value does not increment 3 times, only once i.e.: image_6, image_6, image_6 instead of image_6, image_7, image_8

Comment: Why are you doing it in a loop? The last ID doesn't change during the loop.

Comment: It sounds like you need to get the last ID once, before the loop, the do a loop that increments starting from there.

Comment: I moved this `var lastBox = $( 'input[name="pics[]"]' ).last().data("id");
   var lastId = parseInt(lastBox.slice(6));` to just before the loop and it still does the same thing. hmmm

Comment: Isn't it just repeating the same thing by doing lastId + 1? In other words, if the last id is 5 then in the loop it is just doing 5 + 1, 5 + 1, 5 +1 because lastId = 5

Comment: Are you looking at the edit I did several minutes ago?

Comment: Okay, tried that but still have the same problem. Just repeating image_6, image_6, image_6

Comment: I've created an executable snippet that shows that it works.

Comment: It must be something else wrong on my side. I updated my initial question to show the whole code instead of just the one section.

Comment: I can't see any problem in the code you added. There's no way that `total` can stay the same during the `$.each` loop.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you. I copied your `.prepend()` loop to my answer, and it's working correctly.

Comment: I see the problem. You're prepending the new elements to the front. But when you want to get the highest ID, you're getting the last one, not the first one.

Comment: The problem isn't happening in the loop, it's when you add new elements in separate calls to this code.

Comment: Hmm. What do you suggest in order to fix it?

Comment: Either use `.append()` instead of `.prepend()`, or use `.first()` instead of `.last()`.

Comment: Hmm. I used append and it now works! But the problem is that I want the newly uploaded images to show up first and not last, which is why I used .prepend()

Comment: Then use `.first()` instead of `.last()`